Has there been any research on effective caffeine alternatives for those with ADHD?
I'm one of those people with ADHD for whom caffeine, when it affects me at all, has a calming effect, rather than making me more alert and awake.  I've done a bunch of Googling on how caffeine affects those with ADHD compared to a typical person and, from what I can tell, it seems like there hasn't been a ton of research on the topic, but from what research has been done, as well as theory of how stimulants in general affect those with ADHD compared to those without the condition, it's not surprising that many people with ADHD would experience the opposite effect of caffeine as a neurotypical person would.
My question is, has there been any peer reviewed research on whether other drug classes might help those with ADHD with daytime drowsiness to a similar degree as caffeine tends to do for neurotypical people?
Note that I'm not asking for medical advice -- I wouldn't start taking even a new OTC med without first checking with my doctor or pharmacist about potential interactions with the medications I'm on. I'm just curious about what, if anything, current research has to say on the subject.
